# Some question about wso2 4.0.0 Active active deployment

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I have deployed API manager 4.0.0 All-in-one on 2 VMs. I am using Mysql as DB which is on a separate VM and I am sharing the databases as mentioned in the document. Now I am trying to cluster these 2 nodes as mentioned in this [document](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/single-node/configuring-an-active-active-deployment/). There are a few things that are not clear to me from this document.

If I give the https_endpoint with domain "gw.am.wso2.com" behind the gateway. environments, I need to add 8243 in my reverse proxy server, or not, it fails when trying out API in the console. Why?